# Is there a standard way for form layout in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, layout

Here's my forms layout:

```
    <body>
        <p>Note that this form doesn't actually do anything 
        except illustrate the Required Field Validator.</p>

        <form id="frmValidator" method="post" runat="server">
            Usuario:
            <asp:TextBox id="txtUserName" runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="userNameValidator" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" ErrorMessage='<img src="../Images/no.png">' runat="server" />

            <br />

            Contrasena:
            <asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" runat="server" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="passwordValidator" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage='<img src="../Images/no.png">' runat="server" />

            <br />
            <asp:button id="btnSubmit" text="Submit" runat="server" />
        </form>

        <p>Hint: Try submitting it before you enter something.</p>
    </body>
```

This is a simple layout for just learning purposes, but they align themselves badly. They just smooch together.

Someone suggested I just prace the 'space' key to create the whitespace between them, but that doesn't align them at all. They can never be correctly aligned.

Someone said use tables, but I loathe the idea of using tables for layout.

> How can I achieve a simple
>   organizational style between these two
>   fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Creasey's answer.

```
<div style="width=150">Usuario:</div>
<asp:TextBox id="txtUserName" runat="server" />
```

...

```
<div style="width=150">Contrasena:</div>
<asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap you labels in a div with a class. Then set the min-width the label class so that it is as wide as you need it, then all your fields/labels will line up.

Answer (score 0):

How about padding them so they're not smooshed together? Of course, you may want to create a css class instead of the style attribute, but you get the point.

As far as a standard for ASP.NET, just use good standard CSS. There's nothing fundamentally different with ASP.NET than any other web programming language.

```
<form id="frmValidator" method="post" runat="server">
            <div style="padding:5px;">
                Usuario:
                <asp:TextBox id="txtUserName" runat="server" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="userNameValidator" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" ErrorMessage='<img src="../Images/no.png">' runat="server" />

            </div>
            <div style="padding:5px;">
                Contrasena:
                <asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" runat="server" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="passwordValidator" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage='<img src="../Images/no.png">' runat="server" />

            </div>
            <div style="padding:5px;">
                <asp:button id="btnSubmit" text="Submit" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Thank you that illustrated padding very clearly. However, I mean the separations between: "usuario" and <textbox>. The label and the field are very close together.

Comment: oh...try using '&nbsp;', it's a non-breaking space.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a template or an form generator. A great starting point for solutions is:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/

:-)

Answer (score 0):

No need for extra `<div>`'s - that's what CSS is for!

Here's a basic example using what ASP would render as HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/qWcpN/

And here's the code for it in case you don't want to look at the link.

HTML:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtUserName" Text="Username" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtUserName" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="userNameValidator" CssClass="formError" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" ErrorMessage='Username is required!' />

<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword" Text="Password" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtPassword" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="passwordValidator" CssClass="formError" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage='Password is required!'  />

<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmit" text="Submit" />
```

CSS:

```
label{
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
input[type='text'],
input[type='password']{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:3px;
}

button,
input[type='button'],
input[type='submit']{
    padding:5px;
}

.formError{
    background:#F00;
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    max-width:300px;
    padding:3px;
}​
```